How to show this unicode character on html? &#61598;
I have a problem on showing this Unicode character in the browser: &#61598; (). Even on Google search bar it's not working. I already have the <meta charset="utf-8"> but still not showing. This is the sample text with its Unicode:
REPISQ02120 10
I expect it to be look like this.

Where does this character come from? Do you know what fonts might support it?

Read https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html and take a look here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/F09E/fontsupport.htm

The character "" (U+F09E) is a character in the Private Use Area (PUA). Unicode defines three Private Use Area (PUA) blocks (U+E000..U+F8FF, U+F0000..U+FFFFD, U+100000..U+10FFFD), where characters in these blocks have no official character semantics. They are intended for private exchange of data where characters not defined by Unicode are required.
HTML defines three types of Character references:

Named character references – a small set of mnemonic codes to represent specific characters. Commonly used for reserved characters, e.g. &amp;, &lt; and &gt;.
Decimal numeric character reference (NCR) – characters represented by the decimal value of the Unicode codepoint, e.g. &#125184; for , where the # in the NCR indicates that a number follows it representing the numeric value of the Unicode codepoint.
Hexadecimal numeric character reference (NCR)  – characters represented by the hexadecimal value of the Unicode codepoint, e.g. &#x1e900; for , where the x in the NCR indicates that the following number is a hexadecimal, rather than a decimal number.

"" (U+F09E) has no specific reference glyph or name, and its display is dependent on the font used. Most fonts will not have a glyph for the codepoint, and the fonts that do contain this codepoint will assign different characters to this codepoint.
To display this character, you could include it as an actual character , a decimal NCR (&#61598;), or a hexadecimal NCR (&#xF09E;). It may be better to use a hexadecimal NCR.
Since it is a PUA character, you need to apply markup and styling to the character and use a web font specifically for that character.
I don't know what character/glyph you are expecting or what font it is from. So you'll need to create the Necessary CSS rules.
Try:
<span class="pua_F09E">&#xF09E;</span>

and for the CSS:
.pua_F09E {
    font-family: 'Required_font_family`;
}

applying the appropriate font name to the CSS rule, and adding a web font that supports the required glyph for the specified codepoint. It might be worthwhile subsetting the font.
So for the example above:
<p>REPISQ02120<span class="pua_F09E">&#xF09E;</span> 10</p>


Maybe explaining the meaning of NCR and PUA may improve the answer.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I'll amend the answer, but considering the question referenced an NCR, I'd assumed knowledge of NCRs implied in the question.  Regarding PUA, that is both a simple and complex topic. The character isn't from MARC-21, MUFI, CYFI, RUFI, TITUS or SIL. I assume it's not legacy usage from Chinese standards. If it's from Adobe, Microsoft or Apple then there is likely a Unicode character that should be used instead. I have no idea if it's from a legacy symbol style font or Hanyang or Jeju usage. It's unlikely to be CSUR/UCSUR since a single character was referenced.

Note: my comment is general, to improve the site. If you write what it is the abbreviation (and do not assume too much from question without writing it down), will help getting your answer googeable and so you will get more links from "duplicate" and reputations. When answering, considering that (SO is a reference site, not a forum).
